# Moving Azure Virtual Machine which is Domain Controller to another region

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, azure

I want to move an existing Virtualized Domain Controller from North Central Azure Region to East Region.

I am aware about how to move VHDs and basically migrate it to another region.

Though my concern is specific to this issue:

> You should shut down and restart a VM that runs the domain controller
>   role in Azure within the guest operating system instead of using the
>   Shut Down option in the Azure Management Portal. Today, using the
>   Management Portal to shut down a VM causes the VM to be deallocated. A
>   deallocated VM has the advantage of not incurring charges, but it also
>   resets the VM-GenerationID, which is undesirable for a DC. When the
>   VM-GenerationID is reset, the invocationID of the AD DS database is
>   also reset, the RID pool is discarded, and SYSVOL is marked as
>   non-authoritative.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156090.aspx#BKMK_Safe

Domain controller is running as Windows Server 2012 R2.

What is the safest way to move Domain Controller Virtual Machine and what are the considerations?

Should I clone the Virtual Machine? i.e. capture the VM and then import it into new region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't migrate the VM at all.  Create a new VM in the new region, use a media install for ADDS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770654(v=ws.10).aspx) then let the replication catch up. This could be from a disk you added to the existing DC that you move. Once complete, demote the old DC, and remove it.

Comment: Exactly, do this. Moving the DC to a new region will get a new VM-GenerationID, there is no way to avoid it. Create a New DC, replicate, move FSMO roles then decommission.